# Image getting out of parent td when it is rotated by 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image inside td and I am trying to rotate it by 90 degrees, but I gets out of the table.

I am using `transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bimbari/ck9vwhs6/

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');

var angle = 0;

document.getElementById('rotate-clockwise').onclick = function() {
  angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
  img.className = "rotate" + angle;
};

document.getElementById('rotate-counterclockwise').onclick = function() {
  angle = (angle - 90) % 360;
  if (angle < 0) angle = angle + 360;
  img.className = "rotate" + angle;
};
```

```css
table > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#img {
  transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
}
#img.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#img.rotate180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%, -100%);
}
#img.rotate270 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<a title="Rotate counterclockwise" id="rotate-counterclockwise" href="#">Rotate counterclockwise</a> | <a title="Rotate clockwise" id="rotate-clockwise" href="#">Rotate clockwise</a> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img id="img" src='http://www.malmas.ch/linksbutton.jpg' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you're rotating the image, and not the td itself?

Comment: Yep, it does. I'm guessing you don't have the chance to rotate the container? Is there a different if you set a height of the parent, or just auto?

Comment: You could probably cheat by adding display: table-row to the image :)

Comment: The image is variable and it can change. I don't know its width and height and i cannot set it to a fixed value.

Comment: @tony.gustafsson I tried it with display table, i does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/bimbari/ck9vwhs6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, CSS3 transform rotate won't change the Metrics of the image. I meant, height of image object won't be transposed to width of the image object. That's why td won't auto grow to fit img.

For that, you should use javascript like:

```
function GetBox () {
        var img = document.getElementById ("myImg");

        if (img.getBoundingClientRect) {        // Internet Explorer, Firefox 3+, Google Chrome, Opera 9.5+, Safari 4+
            var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect ();
            x = rect.left;
            y = rect.top;
            w = rect.right - rect.left;
            h = rect.bottom - rect.top;

            alert (" Left: " + x + "\n Top: " + y + "\n Width: " + w + "\n Height: " + h); // This height can be used to resize td.
        }
        else {
            alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should edit first is that actual rotate value from `rotate(90deg)` to `rotateZ(90deg)` and check if that helps at all.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotatez

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with using this inside a table.  Table layouts are notoriously difficult to size properly.